# Как заставить pyinstaller exe брать актуальные данные с py файла

Tags: python, pyinstaller

У меня есть `main.exe` скомпилированный с помощью `pyinstaller`.

в файле `main.py(main.exe)` есть такие строки:

```
import config

while memu_counter < config.memu_restart_counter:
    ...
```

Так же, есть файл `config.py`, в котором находиться переменная:

```
memu_restart_counter = 20
```

Я хочу в дальнейшем изменять `memu_restart_counter`, но `exe` запоминает только одно значение перед сборкой. Как можно сделать, чтобы можно было каждый раз обновлять данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете решить эту проблему, создав отдельный файл, который будет хранить данные конфигурации. Вместо того, чтобы хранить данные конфигурации в самом main.py, вы можете хранить их в файле, например, config.txt и прочитать их в main.py каждый раз при запуске программы.
Например
config.txt:

```
memu_restart_counter = 20
```

main.py

```
def read_config():
    with open("config.txt", "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    config = {}
    for line in data:
        key, value = line.strip().split("=")
        config[key.strip()] = int(value.strip())
    return config

config = read_config()
memu_counter = 0
while memu_counter < config["memu_restart_counter"]:
    # do something
    memu_counter += 1
```

Теперь, когда вы измените memu_restart_counter в config.txt, изменения будут видны в main.py при каждом запуске.